# WCF:The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I searched so many forums but i am confused which setting i have to do in web.config file and where i have to do? I have two application seperate 1.Asp.net application 2.WCF Service Application; i added service reference in my Asp.net application.these applications are not hosted on IIS i am testing it on my local machine.Please provide me guide line to pass uploaded file to Service application.

Asp.net application web.config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                 maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:7147/WCFService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" contract="HostedWCF.IWCF"
         name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service Application Web.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DPOConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=s15346491\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DatabaseName;Uid=UserID;Password=password;"/>-->
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SWAPNIL-PC;Initial Catalog=PayrollNet;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogoPath" value="C:\Users\HARSH12\Desktop\New Conversion 26-7-2013\ConstructionApplication\CMSERPService\ErrorLog\ErrorLog.txt" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="WCFService.svc" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is your `http://localhost:7147/WCFService.svc` running properly? check it in browser

Comment: yes  it is working properly

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                 realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: ok,but in which web.config i have to add Server application web.config or Asp.net application web.config

Comment: After doing required changes i test it on WCFTestClient but it shows me config like Asp.net application web.config(given above)

Comment: Add this in application web.config